# Launchscreen not visible with a capacitor app

Tags: xcode, capacitor, xcode-storyboard, launch-screen

I have generated an xcode project with capacitor.js 5.5.1
In my xcode project I have a a working storyboard (auto generated) I have check "Use as launchscreen" plus "is initial view controller" and in my app settings I've selected the storyboard in "launch screen file"

But I keep getting a black screen at loading

Does someone have an idea?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I have recreated another Launch Screen with a regenerated picture and now everything works fine.